# Detect a beep of a certain frequency and duration

Tags: c, audio, fft, portaudio

How can one detect a beep from audio data with a known frequency and duration but unknown time of arrival?
I am trying to implement a bandpass filter to ignore the sounds of any unknown frequency. I haven't succeeded yet. Once I succeed in that, I will check the the amplitude of sound if it exceeds a certain threshold for my fixed amount of time. That should detect the beep. I have been told that a Fourier transform can also be used to detect the beep.

Which strategy is better?

Furthermore, listening to audio recordings, I have come to believe that Windows or the sound driver of my laptop (Inspiron 15R) is applying some sort of a noise cancelling filter on the microphone input. Is this common on laptops? If it is, is there any way to get the untouched real audio from the mic? I am using portaudio library to get the sound.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to `dsp.stackexchange.com`!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and most common method for this kind of tone detection task (where the tone frequency is known *a priori*) is the [Goertzel Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm). It's effectively just a single bin DFT at the frequency of interest - you take the output and low pass filter it and when it exceeds an empirically-derived threshold then you have detected your tone.